What kind of interesting properties that make exponential cone attractive?
I am a network engineer who is studying some optimization problems in the field of communication theory mostly for pleasure. Out of pure curiosity, I see that there is some optimization problem in which this logarithmic constraint appear  $y\log \left( {1 + \frac{x}{y}} \right) \ge t \Leftrightarrow x + y \ge y{e^{\frac{t}{y}}}$
It seems that this constraint can be turned into some sort of things is called as exponential cone.
The exponential cone object is defined as follow:
$K_{exp} = {( (x_1, x_2, x_3) : x_1 \geq x_2 e^{x_3/x_2}, x_2 > 0 )} ∪ {( (x_1, 0, x_3) : x_1 \geq 0, x_3 \leq 0 )}.$
A little bit search on google schorlar return a lot of results but due to my limited knowledge of convex analysis I do not understand what is really nice about these "exponential cone" object.
Therefore, my question is "What kind of interesting properties that make exponential cone attractive for convex optimization ?"
Since this question is quite broad I hope that you could as least show some criteria for example: presentability, or maybe it make the interior point method converge faster, etc...
Would you kindly help me with this ?
Thank you for your enthusiasm

Are you aware of the connection with the important $W$ Lambert function ? Here is an article (btw with vietnamian name authors)

Uh this is the first time I have seen it

About $W$ function, if you browse Math SE you will see that it appears rather often ; see for example my recent answer here

The exponential cone is a basic building block which, as you probably found out, can be used to express many functions involving exp and log one is interested in optimizing, as well as geometric programming (GP). It is the first interesting direction to extend interior-point conic solvers beyond the classical SOCP and SDP.

Mathematical attractiveness:
A main difference of power and exponential cones, in comparison with positive orthant, Lorentz, or semidefinite cones, is that they are not symmetric, which makes them more attractive for researchers.
Theoretical  attractiveness:
From a theoretical point of view, optimization problems with exponential cones can be solved (finding  an $\epsilon$-optimal solution for any $\epsilon>0$) in polynomial time using the barrier interior-point method when the barrier function is $\phi(t)=-\log t$ (see Section 11.5 of [1]) In fact, it can be shown that
$$- \log g_1(x,y,z)- \log g_2(x,y,z)- \log g_3(x,y,z) \\ = -\log (y \log(z/y) - x) - \log y - \log z$$
is a self-concordant function [2] where $g_1(x,y,z)$, $g_2(x,y,z)$, and $g_3(x,y,z)$ define the exponential cone as follows:
$$\mathcal K_{\text{exp}}=\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid ye^{x/y} \leq z, y > 0 \} \\= \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid g_1(x,y,z)=y \log(z/y) - x \ge 0, g_2(x,y,z)=y>0,g_3(x,y,z)=z>0 \}.$$
Computational  attractiveness:
Moreover, efficient primal-dual interior point algorithms have been recently developed and made available in cvx and mosek for solving such problems, which have been successful and more efficient compared to the barrier method in practice; see this paper [3].
Application  attractiveness:
Due to the recent computational progress and availability of solvers, several studies have recently reformulated new or old optimization problems as exponential cone optimization models, which can be solved more efficiently or more easily using the existing solvers instead of implementing specialized algorithms. A nice new one is the reformulation of Lambert function as cone optimization model, mentioned in a comment by @JeanMarie. Another example is the reformulation of portfolio optimization with Entropic Value-at-Risk as an exponential conic model given in [5], whereas the problem has been convexified and solved earlier by specialized convex optimization methods in [6].

More details:
Consider the following optimization model:
$$\min \quad f_0(x) \\
\text{s.t.:}\,  Ax=b, \, f_i(x)\le 0,\, i=1,\dots,m, \tag{1}$$
which is assumed to have an optimal solution $x^*$ and a strict feasible solution $x_0$, i.e., $Ax_0=b \, f_i(x_0)< 0,\, i=1,\dots,m$.
Assume that both functions $f_0$ and $ \phi(x)$, defined below:
$$ \phi(x)= -\sum_{i=1}^m \log (-f_i(x)), \tag{2}$$
are self-concordant. Then, from the key result presented in Section 11.5 of [1], it is known that there is a barrier interior-point algorithm that can find an $\epsilon$-optimal solution $x^*_\epsilon$, i.e., $f(x^*_\epsilon)-f(x^*)< \epsilon$ such that the number of its iterations is order of $O\left (\log\frac 1\epsilon \, \sqrt{m} \right).$
Now consider the following exponential cone programming model:
$$\min \quad f_0(x) \\
\text{s.t.:}\,  Ax=b, \\
w=Bx \in\prod_{i=1}^{k} \mathcal K_{\text{exp}, i}, w \in \mathbb R^{3k} \tag{3}$$
where each $\mathcal K_{\text{exp}, i}$ is an exponential cone: $$\mathcal K_{\text{exp}}=\{ (w_i,w_{i+1},w_{i+2}) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid w_{i+1} e^{w_{i+2}/w_{i+1}} \leq w_{i}, w_{i+1} > 0 \}.$$
Model (3) can be rewritten as
$$\min \quad f_0(x) \\
\text{s.t.:}\,  Ax=b, w=Bx \\
f_i(w_i,w_{i+1},w_{i+2})=-w_{i+1} \log(w_{i+2}/w_{i+1}) + w_{i} \le 0,\\ g_i(w_i,w_{i+1},w_{i+2})=-w_{i+1}<0,h_i(w_i,w_{i+1},w_{i+2})=-w_{i+2}<0, \, i=1,\dots,k.$$
This model is of the initial form (1) given above with $m=3k$. So we can apply the  barrier algorithm. Fortunately, it is also known that for each $i \in [k]$
$$- \log (- f_i(w_i,w_{i+1},w_{i+2}))- \log (- g_i(w_i,w_{i+1},w_{i+2}))- \log (- h_i(w_i,w_{i+1},w_{i+2}))$$
is a self-concordant function. Hence, function $\phi$ defined earlier in (2) for this model is also self-concordant. Finally, when $f_0$ is self-concordant and $x_0$ and $x^*$ exist, any $\epsilon$-optimal of the the above reformulation of the exponential cone programming model can be obtained in $O\left (\log\frac 1\epsilon \, \sqrt{3k} \right)=O\left (\log\frac 1\epsilon \, \sqrt{k} \right)$ iterations.

Thank you but is there anyway to determine the complexity of solving an exponential cone program ?

You are welcom! Yes, as stated in the third part of the answer, it is polynomial like SOCP and SDP,  by an appropriate implementation of the barrier interior-point method for self-concordant functions.

For self-concordant functions, the number of iterations required by the barrier method described in Section 11.5 of Convex Optimization with $\mu$ given in (11.28) to find a solution with fixed duality gap $\epsilon$ (error bound; Section 11.5.3) is of order $\sqrt{m}$ (see  (11.29)) where $m$ is the total number of inequality constraints. For example, if the model consists of a linear objective function, $Ax=b$, and $k$ exponential cone constraints, for given $\epsilon$, the method finds a solution in $O(\log \frac1\epsilon\sqrt{3k})= O(\log \frac1\epsilon\sqrt{k})$ iterations (like SOCP).

I have upvoted your answer but in which book can I find this fact " if the model consists of a linear objective function, and k exponential cone constraints, for a given $\epsilon$ the method finds a solution in $O(\log \frac1\epsilon\sqrt{3k})= O(\log \frac1\epsilon\sqrt{k})$" ?

@TuongNguyenMinh Thank you! I will provide more details as I can spare some time. It is a consequnce of the key general result presented in Section 11.5 of the book [2], just click on the link given above to get the pdf. Have you read this section?

I have search the keyword "exponential cone" for the book convex optimization by professor Boyd but my search return nothing. In section 11.5.1, this book only said that "The complexity analysis given below therefore applies to LPs, QPs, and QCQPs."

Please first read the general result given in Section 11.5. As the function that I gave in the my answer is also self concordant, the same result can be obtained for ECP, similarly as for LP, QCQP, SOCP, etc.

Amir my mathematical ability is a little bad , could you kindly show me where does the number $3$ from $O(\log \frac1\epsilon\sqrt{3k})= O(\log \frac1\epsilon\sqrt{k})$ come from ?

@TuongNguyenMinh Sure! I will add more details today! To write an exponetial cone as a standard form used in 11.5, we need three inequality constraints (see $g_1$, $g_2$, and $g_3$ in my answer.)

@TuongNguyenMinh  I just added more details. Hope they are helpful.

Thank you ! now I realize that it is quite similar to this question
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4400613/is-conic-programs-with-exponential-cone-solvable-in-polynomial-time?noredirect=1&lq=1

@TuongNguyenMinh  Yes the part on algorithm is also asked in that question.  Your question is on all aspects of ECP.
